# True or false? For every integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

*Task from a test-exam (in German): http://docdro.id/YncVusx*

> True or false? For every integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,  $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$
>   is a field.

I'm not sure what's meant by $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$. Let's take $k=5$, that would be $\mathbb{Z}_{5} = \left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$? It would make sense I think, well nothing else comes to my mind of what it could mean.

So understanding it like that, I would say that the statement is false. Let $k=0$ then not all axioms of a field will be satisfied. To be more specific, field has an axiom where zero is necessarily excluded.

---

Can you please tell me if I did it correctly and if not, how to do it correctly?

Comment: The usually chosen representatives for the residue classes modulo $\;5\;$ are $\;\{0,1,2,3,4\}\;$ . Of course, we have that $\;5=0\pmod 5\;$. I think you may be needing to go back to your notes ...and $\;\Bbb Z_k\;$ is a field iff $\;k\;$ is a prime (and thus $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ is , in fact, a field...) .

Comment: I think it's more common to say $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is integer modulo $k$, so $\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. As for $\mathbb{Z}_0$, that really needs clarification as it doesn't make sense to say modulo $0$. But even for nonzero $k$ $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is not a field as long as $k$ is non-integer

Comment: In the set {1,2,3,4,5} 5 plays the role of 0.  $5 + a = a$ and $5*a = 5$  In your notation, {1,2,3,4,5} *is* a field because $1*1 = 1; 2*3 = 1; 3*2 = 1; 4*4 = 1$ so all non-zero terms have multiplicative inverses.  But it is easier and more common to say $\mathbb Z_5 =${0,1,2,3,4} (or {-2,-1,0,1,2}).  What about $\mathbb Z_6$ = {0,1,2,3,4,5}.  Is that a field? can you solve $3x = 1$?

Comment: Hmm, you do have a point.  I don't know that $\mathbb Z_{-5}$ has a definition and $Z_0$ would have to be the empty set.  $Z_1 = {0}$ would be the trivial field where $0 = 1; 0*0 = 0; 0 + 0 = 0$.  I imagine that is a typo though and they meant $k \ge 2$.  Which may or may not be true.  (That's up to you to figure out.)  (Obviously I'm hinting that it is not always true... but it is sometimes.)

Comment: Technically speaking $\mathbb Z_5$ is not the set {1,2,3,4,5} but the set of *modulo classes* {[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]} where [i] is not just the integer, i; it is the *set* of *all* integers {i + 5k}.  So [0] = [5] = {...., -20,-15,-10, -5, 0 , 5,10,15...} and [3] = {....,-7,-2,3,8,13,...}, etc.  So [3] + [4] ={3+4 + 5k} = {7 + 5k} = {2 + 5j} = [2]. and [3][4] = {3$\times$4 + 5k} = {12+5k} = {2+5j} = [2].

Comment: @fleablood: I would say $\mathbb Z_0$ ought to be $\mathbb Z/\langle 0\rangle$, or in other words $\mathbb Z$ itself,

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Yes, you are  correct and I was wrong, now that I think more about it (and $\mathbb Z$ is not a field, of course).  But what (if anything) would $\mathbb Z_{-6}$ be?  And if $k \not \in \mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z_k$ defined?

Comment: Oh, duh, $\mathbb Z_{-6} = \mathbb Z_{6}$!  But we are getting a bit technical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_k$ is the ring of integers modulo $k$. By convention $k\geq 2$ is understood implicitly. One writes $\mathbb{Z}_k=\left\{\bar{z}\mid z\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$. By definition $\bar{n}=\bar{m}$ if and only if $k\mid (n-m)$.

It is a well known fact that $\bar{z}$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_k$ if and only if $\text{gcd}(z,k)=1$. You can show this as an application of Bezout's theorem.

Using the above fact it's easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is a field if and only if $k$ is prime.

Comment: You're missing the point. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are not numbers but equivalence classes under the equivalence relation given by having the same remainder after division by $5$. So $\dots=-9=-4=1=6=11=16=\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z_5$ means the integers $0,1,2,3,4$ with the addition and multiplication modulo 5 operations.  (Where $a + b = a+b \pm 5k$ so that the result is between $0$ and $4$ [e.x $3+4 = 2$ (which is $5 + 2=7$)] and $a*b = a*b \pm 5k$ [e.x. $3*4 = 2$ (which is $12 = 2 + 2*5$)].

$\mathbb Z_5$ is indeed a field.

But is $\mathbb Z_6$?  Hint: what is $2*3$?  Hint 2:  Can you solve $3x = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Not for composite $k$. Fields lack zero divisors, but e.g. $2\times 2=0$ in $\mathrm{Z}_4$.

Answer (score 1):

By $\Bbb Z_n$ we mean the ring of integers modulo $n$. This partitions the integers into *equivalence classes*, $[x]$, where $y\in[x]$ if $y\equiv x\pmod{n}$; we shall take $[1]$ as unity and $[n]=[0]$ as the zero class (for brevity we shall drop the brackets when calculating with classes modulo a number). Now if $n$ is composite this ring will have *proper divisors of zero*, and so will fail to have an inverse for all of its elements, and subsequently will fail to be a field. For example in $\Bbb Z_{12}$, $3\cdot 4\equiv0\pmod{12}$ and so $3$ and $4$ are divisors of zero modulo $12$ and so not invertible.

However if $n$ is a prime, $p$, say, then every element bar the zero is invertible since every element is relatively prime to $p$. Then $\Bbb Z_p$ is what is termed a *finite integral domain* (these are always fields), these having no proper divisors of zero, i.e., if $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$. To see why consider the map
$$f\colon \Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z_p:\quad x\mapsto xy$$
Then the kernel of $f$ is trivial, $\ker(f)=\{0\}$, by definition of zero divisors, and so $f$ is injective. Moreover this shows $f$ is surjective since $\Bbb Z_p$ is finite.

Hence since $1\in\Bbb Z_p$ and $f$ is surjective, then $\exists x\in \Bbb Z_p$ s.t. $f(x)=xy=1$, and this has $x$ the product inverse of $y$ and so $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field.